# no main manifest attribute, in ---jar

Tags: java, wsdl, executable-jar, soap-client, wsdl2java

I'm currently working as a java developer but I'm still learning things.
I've received a task at my company to test an API from a third-part software that my company uses,
that was never done and we don't have any experience about it.

The guys sent me a folder with some WSDL files, XSD files and some Jar Files(The guys that sent-me the files are not from IT and could not help-me about how it works):

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcABD.png)

I'm not used to this kind of API (WSDL), and I have no clue of how I'm supposed to test it.
When I try to execute the jar files I get the following error (in all of them):

"no main manifest attribute, in ws-assessment-interface-types-IQ10.jar"

I tried to use Eclipse, create a Dynamic Web Project with a Web Service Client importing the WSDL + XSD files and all I can get is a list of the classes + inputs but I can't invoke them.

Can someone give-me a tip about this kind of API, how it supposed to work, the jar files I should use as imports in my code? Any clue would be really helpful.

Comment: *"no main manifest attribute, in ws-assessment-interface-types-IQ10.jar"* That suggests that you tried to run that jar as an application. It might not contain an application. It's even possible that none of those jars contains an application

Comment: You could try https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/55-find-java-classes-that-are-applications that I wrote years ago. Put it in the same directory as the rest of your jars, change to that directory in cmd.exe and do `java -jar findapps.jar .` and it will tell you the jars that contain applications.EDIT: that's what *I* do but you could just run it from the compiled source

Comment: Yes, opening those jars, all I can find is a com.---.--- with a bunch of .class files, that are all compiled. In META-INF -> MANIFEST.MF there is no field "MainClass:", these files should be libraries in my code then?

Comment: Yes, if there's no MainClass then you should probably treat it as a library